# Cuda Paclet for 11.3

Tags: cudalink

I have Wolfram Mathematica 11.3 installed on Ubuntu 16.04. My card is GTX-750Ti. I had "Installed" the CUDAResources-Lin64-11.3 over the internet. Can I "create" a Paclet of it so that I don't have to download 1.3 GB again, if I ever need to reinstall? The Wolfram webpage has an older paclet for download.

Comment: You *don't* have to re-download unless you delete the contents of your `$UserBaseDirectory` (or there is a new version of the CUDA resources).

Comment: The term "to create a paclet" does not make sense here.  Basically, some large components of Mathematica are not included as many people may not need them.  These are automatically downloaded upon first use.  They only need to be downloaded once and they are stored in your `$UserBaseDirectory` (not in Mathematica's installation directory).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I will not vote to close this. Maybe a short answer can be written that explains where these paclets live and that you can (in theory) simply copy them. That might be helpful for others.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid downloading  1.3 GB of (CUDA Resource ) Software if I install the same Mathematica on another machine ( not in the same network). Hence the question. Can I just copy the contents of the ~/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CUDAResources-Lin64-11.3.154  directory to that machine?